# Добавление класса при нажатии на кнопку удаление класса при нажатии на весь блок. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

При нажатии на button нужно чтобы к классу content1 добавлялся selected. и при нажатии на весь блок , класс selected должен удаляться. 
Я сделал добавление класса , никак не могу понять как сделать чтобы класс сразу же не удалялся при первом клике по button.

```
function addClickListener(card) {
var button = card.querySelector('.myBtn');
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
card.classList.add('selected');
});
}
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.content1');
for (var i = 0 ; i < cards.length;i++){
    addClickListener(cards[i]);
}
```

html

```
<div class="content1" onclick="myFunc">
       <img src="img/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82-12001.jpg" alt="">
       <div class="content">

       <p class="header">
           Представительский люкс
       </p>
       <p class="text">
           Эксклюзивный номер с панорамным видом на центр города Москвы
       </p>
       <hr>
       <p class="price">
           от <span class="price1">7900</span> руб./сутки
       </p>
       <button  class="myBtn">Забронировать</button>
       </div>
```

```js
function addClickListener(card) {
  var button = card.querySelector('.myBtn');
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    card.classList.add('selected');
  });
}
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.content1');
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  addClickListener(cards[i]);
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="content1" onclick="myFunc">
  <img src="img/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82-12001.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="content">

    <p class="header">
      Представительский люкс
    </p>
    <p class="text">
      Эксклюзивный номер с панорамным видом на центр города Москвы
    </p>
    <hr>
    <p class="price">
      от <span class="price1">7900</span> руб./сутки
    </p>
    <button class="myBtn">Забронировать</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function addClickListener(card) {
  card.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.remove('selected');
  });
  var button = card.querySelector('.myBtn');
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    card.classList.add('selected');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
}
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.content1');
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  addClickListener(cards[i]);
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="content1">
  <img src="img/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82-12001.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="content">

    <p class="header">
      Представительский люкс
    </p>
    <p class="text">
      Эксклюзивный номер с панорамным видом на центр города Москвы
    </p>
    <hr>
    <p class="price">
      от <span class="price1">7900</span> руб./сутки
    </p>
    <button class="myBtn">Забронировать</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: почему не работает без e.stopPropagation()?

Comment: @damcha Потому что без `e.stopPropagation()` событие всплывет до родителя, а там - `this.classList.remove('selected');`.